# Avoid new page before specific section in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context, page

I have enable put a blank page in each section:

```
\setuphead[section][page=yes]
```

I want to not to insert a page blank after some specific sections:

Eg.

```
\section{Section 1}%starts a new page after
bla...
\section{Section 2}% I need this section does not start a new page
bla...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option might be to define a new section command:

```
\setuphead[section][page=yes]

\definehead[sectionnopage][section][page=no]

\starttext
Some text here.
\section[title=Section 1]
bla...
\sectionnopage[title=Section 2]
bla...
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\disablepagebreaks` in a group around the section, but I don't know whether this has any side effects.

```
\setuphead[section][page=yes]

\starttext

\section{Section 1}
bla...

{\disablepagebreaks\section{Section 2}}
bla...

\stoptext
```

There seems to be no counterpart to `\disablepagebreaks`.  It's still possible to define one, but keep in mind that this is not supported and might break in unexpected ways.

```
\unprotect
\let\normal_page_breaks_process\page_breaks_process
\unexpanded\def\enablepagebreaks%
    {\let\page_breaks_process\normal_page_breaks_process}
\protect

\setuphead[section][page=yes]

\starttext

\section{Section 1}
bla...

\disablepagebreaks
\section{Section 2}
\enablepagebreaks
bla...

\stoptext
```